# How do I share an object between UIViewControllers on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, uiviewcontroller

My application is a tab bar application, with a separate view controller for each tab.

I have an object in my first view controller (A) which contains all my stored application data (Please ignore NSUserDefaults for this) which needs to be accessed by the second view controller (B) when I press a button on it. How can I achieve this in the best way?

Comment: This question is very similar to a question that I asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053704/organizing-instance-variables-in-a-view-hierarchy

Comment: True. You can't blame me for not finding it though. It's worded completely different.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

One option you have is to declare your date model as instance variables of your app delegate (as mentioned by other commenters).

Instead of referencing the app delegate as suggested by nevan an alternative is to add a property to your view controller classes (A and B) for your data model.

Say you wanted to share a data model object between your view controllers you can add a property to each:

```
@interface AViewController : UIViewController {
    MyDataModel *model;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) MyDataModel *model;

@end

@interface BViewController : UIViewController {
    MyDataModel *model;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) MyDataModel *model;

@end
```

When you initialise your view controller you can then set this property to the object context initialised previously.

You have mentioned a tab bar controller. If your view controllers are wired through IB all you have to do is to set these parameters in your application delegate `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method, before the tab bar controller is displayed:

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>
{

    MyDataModel *model;
    AViewController *aViewController;
    BViewController *bViewController;
    ...
}

@property (retain) IBOutlet AViewController *aViewController;
@property (retain) IBOutlet BViewController *aViewController;

@end

@implementation MyAppDelegate

...

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{
...

    aViewController.model = model;

    bViewController.model = model;

    [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Don't forget to release the model in your view controller's `dealloc` method.

---

The alternative is to use a singleton object. An simple singleton example:

```
@interface MyDataModel : NSObject
{
}

+ (MyDataModel *) sharedDataModel;

@end

@implementation MyDataModel

static MyDataModel *sharedDataModel = nil;

+ (MyDataModel *) sharedDataModel
{

    @synchronized(self)
    {
        if (sharedDataModel == nil)
        {
            sharedDataModel = [[MyDataModel alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return sharedDataModel;
}

@end
```

You can access this data model from all your view controllers with something similar to the following:

```
MyDataModel *model = [MyDataModel sharedDataModel];
```

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like) stack overflow discussion about singletons.

Comment: I really like this answer. Using pointers to reference the data model from the AppDelegate seems a lot more clean than using a Singleton. This method also seems to keep the coupling to a minimum. Thanks.

Comment: See now I'd have used one of these two methods. But just to confuse me, the Stanford Lecture No.7 says both are no-nos! Check out: http://deimos3.apple.com/WebObjects/Core.woa/Feed/itunes.stanford.edu.3124430053.03124430055 at about 30 mins through. Anyway thanks for this, I'm gonna use a singleton :P

Comment: After watching Lecture 7 that you are referring to, I believe he (Josh Shaffer) is advocating the first approach here. 

You are definitely right that he does not recommend using singleton as it is just another kind of global state. 

When he recommends not using the application delegate, I think he was referring to accessing the application delegate statically and getting your data through there.

His example of how it should be done, i thought was very close to szzsolt's first approach above. Just passing in exactly what your view controller needs.

Answer (score 8):

The most common way I've seen this is to set up the thing you want to access in the app delegate and reference it in other places like this:

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
myStuff = appDelegate.stuff;
```

In the app delegate, set up a stuff variable and use @property and @synthesize as usual.

Some people say that it's not a good approach, since it's the same as using global variables, but it's very common.

Comment: Using a singleton is also a common approach.

Comment: I don't really understand why the accepted answer is better. I used extensively a similar approach before but it just gave me an extra complexity. Passing objects back and forth just was a headache. +1

Comment: @Tibidabo: because holding data in 'appDelegate' is considered as a really bad practice (from OOP & code reusability point of view). Othervise: as a quick & dirty solution, this answer is perfectly o.k.

Answer (score 5):

I like to create a top level Model class that is a singleton and contains all the elements I might need.

It's helpful to also give it a top level load method that populates objects with just the db keys, using the hydrate/dehydrate pattern common in the Apple examples.

Typical usage in the app delegate would be simply,

```
[[MyModel sharedModel] load];
```

And then in a view controller:

```
NSArray *myThing1s = [[MyModel sharedModel] thing1s];
NSArray *myThing2s = [[MyModel sharedModel] thing2s];
```

You can then iterate over your thing1s and thing2s and when you need details, you can just call

```
[myThing1 hydrate];
```

which will populate the object.

Of course, you probably want to use CoreData to manage the persistence from 3.0 onwards.

Comment: Could you post a singleton example in Objective-C that I can use? I'm leaning towards this way, it seems slightly better than Delegate access.

Answer (score 3):

I always create a special object called `DataModel` and use it's singleton `sharedInstance`.

And this object then holds all the app-related-data. No need for accessing *the dreaded* `appDelegate`.

**DataModel.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class MyClass1, MyClass2;

@interface DataModel : NSObject

@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *aString;
@property (assign) BOOL aBool;

@property (strong) MyClass1 *myObject1;
@property (strong) MyClass2 *myObject2;

+ (DataModel *)sharedModel;

@end
```

**DataModel.m**

```
#import "DataModel.h"
#import "Class1.h"
#import "Class2.h"

@implementation DataModel

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        _myObject1 = [[MyClass1 alloc] init];
        _myObject2 = [[MyClass2 alloc] init];
        aBool = NO;
        aString = nil;
    }
    return self;
}

+ (DataModel *)sharedModel
{
    static DataModel *_sharedModel = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceSecurePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&onceSecurePredicate,^
                  {
                      _sharedModel = [[self alloc] init];
                  });

    return _sharedModel;
}

@end
```

And (bacause I'm lazy) i put `DataModel.h` in `application-prefix.pch`.

That way i can access my data from anywhere in the application simply by calling

```
[DataModel sharedModel]
```

Comment: I have used this approach with great success.

Answer (score 0):

Both view controllers should reference a third object (C) as their dataSource; this object (C) containing all the stored application data.

C would be, in this case, the M in the MVC.

Add to each of your ViewControllers the following declarations:

```
// SomeViewController.h
// Before @interface

@class MyDataSource;

// In the interface

IBOutlet MyDataSource *datasource;
@property(retain) IBOutlet MyDataSource *datasource;
```

Comment: Exactly. So how do i do that? Where should I store my data model and how can I access in the correct way to adhere to MVC from both ViewControllers.