# Xcode ios Background image on multiple views

Tags: ios, xcode, background, uiimage, view

I recently found how to program a switch and how to change the background from 1 view.

My question is how to change the background of multiple views (UIImage) when changing the value of the switch.

For example: It's a preference page and when I switch the background of the preferences page changes so the switch works.

Now i want the background (UIImage) of my first view named "**viewcontroller**" to change to the same background as the background of my preferences page.

Comment: you could create a globally available variable (could be a singleton or - not so clean - a public property of app delegate) that holds the background image and each view(controller) would refresh it's background the moment before it becomes visible (appears)

Comment: could you give me a code example please??? I'm not so good in Xcode yet...

Comment: O.k. If you want a more detailed answer you can add the code you use to set the background now ti your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my opinion, there may be a lot of different ways to achieve this. What i would do is save the image name string into  **[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]**.

Such as when the switch value changes, you call

```
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"BackgroundImageName" forKey:@"BackgroundImageOne.jpg"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

and when you set up the background, you could do

```
    NSUserDefaults *userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    UIImage *bgImage;
    if ([userDefault objectForKey:@"BackgroundImageName"])
        bgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[userDefault objectForKey:@"BackgroundImageName"]];
    else
        bgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DEFAULT_NAME"];

    //... Set the bgImage to your background image view ...//
```

Maybe you have to do some changes based on the actual usage. But hope this give you some hints.

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solutions would be to create a public property of application delegate holding your background image.

```
@property (strong) UIImage *globalBackground;
```

In your `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` you should initialize it either to some default image or last saved image.

```
self.globalBackground = [UIImage imageNamed:@"defaultBackground"];
```

Let's say your appDelegate header file is MyAppDelegate.h. You should import it in all the classes that use this default background image mechanism. Or simply add it to your `Prefix.pch` file.

In your settings view controller you would then set:

```
//your background setting handler
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.globalBackground = ... //however you get the selected image
//and here you set the background image of settings view controller
```

Then in each of the view controllets `viewWillAppear:` you set its background in similar manner:

```
MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
//then you use appDelegate.globalBackground the same way you are doing it now
```

If you have a lot of view controllers you might want to consider creating a subclass of `UIViewController` that implements this mechanism (possibly calling it `UIViewControllerWithBackground`) and make all your view controllers subclasses of this class.

Note A: one would (instead of appDelegate's property) typically use a singleton class holding all the settings. It might be considered as a bad (quick & dirty) practice. [More...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16199974/653513)

Note B: for saving the name of last selected background you could use `NSUserDefaults`. This is out of the scope of this question and there is a lot of sample code available out there...

Comment: Thnx for your respons, i'll try it  out

Comment: That not work. If i implement your Code i get error message
````Initializing 'AppDelegate *__strong' with an expression of incompatible type 'id<UIApplicationDelegate> _Nullable'````

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to pass the image, which I saved in Xcode, to a next viewcontroller? Or give it a number and pass that number to a next viewcontroller? For example, when switchone is on, NSNumber = 1, pass it to the next view, and then if (NSNumber == 1) than display "backgroundone.jpg"???